# add subtitles for rows of a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

For a plot like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

f, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharey=True)
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.scatter(x, y)
ax3.scatter(x, 2 * y ** 2 - 1, color='r')
ax4.plot(x, 2 * y ** 2 - 1, color='r')
```

how can I add subtitles for a row?. It should look like this:

[image]

I made "Title1" and "Title2" with photoshop, how can I add them to the plot in python?

Comment: You can use `ax3.set_title('Insert Title Here')` to give a title to each subplot, however this does not appear in the middle of the row....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make a title for a plot with subplots, matplotlib has [`pyplot.suptitle`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle). Since there can only be one `suptitle` per figure it does not solve the problem if you want to have two rows of figures.

Using `plt.text()` one can set text to an axes, which is also not wanted here, so I would suggest to use [`plt.figtext`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figtext)

It may then be required to adjust the spacingbetween the rows of the subplots using `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.3 )`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

f, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharey=True)
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.scatter(x, y)
ax3.scatter(x, 2 * y ** 2 - 1, color='r')
ax4.plot(x, 2 * y ** 2 - 1, color='r')

plt.figtext(0.5,0.95, "A tremendously long title that wouldn't fit above a single figure", ha="center", va="top", fontsize=14, color="r")
plt.figtext(0.5,0.5, "Yet another multi-worded title that needs some space", ha="center", va="top", fontsize=14, color="r")
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.3 )
plt.savefig(__file__+".png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I was hoping for a more elegant solution, but this is convenient.

Answer (score 6):

#### New in matplotlib 3.4.0

We can now do this with built-in **suptitles for subfigures**.

First create a 2x1 subfigure grid via [`Figure.subfigures`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subfigures). Then for each subfigure, give it its own 1x2 subplot grid and suptitle:

```py
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
# fig.suptitle('Figure title')            # set global suptitle if desired

(subfig1, subfig2) = fig.subfigures(2, 1) # create 2x1 subfigures
(ax1, ax2) = subfig1.subplots(1, 2)       # create 1x2 subplots on subfig1
(ax3, ax4) = subfig2.subplots(1, 2)       # create 1x2 subplots on subfig2

subfig1.suptitle('Title 1')               # set suptitle for subfig1
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.scatter(x, y)

subfig2.suptitle('Title 2', color='r')    # set suptitle for subfig2
ax3.scatter(x, 2 * y ** 2 - 1, color='r')
ax4.plot(x, 2 * y ** 2 - 1, color='r')
```

*Note: it's also possible to put subfigures into an existing `plt.subplots` grid via [`Figure.add_subfigure`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subfigures) as shown in [how to plot subfigures](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html).*

[image: suptitled subfigures]

Comment: I prefer this solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding 3 lines of code as below:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

```
f, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharey=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.2, hspace=0.5) 
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.scatter(x, y)
ax3.scatter(x, 2 * y ** 2 - 1, color='r')
ax4.plot(x, 2 * y ** 2 - 1, color='r')

ax1.text(6.1, 1.36, 'Title1', color='r',fontsize=20)
ax3.text(6.1, 1.36, 'Title2', color='b',fontsize=20)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is fairly simple to do; call `set_title` on the subplots

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('ggplot')
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

f, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharey=True)
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_title("a blue line")

ax2.scatter(x, y)
ax2.set_title("cool blue dots")

ax3.scatter(x, 2 * y ** 2 - 1, color='r')
ax3.set_title("cool red dots")

ax4.plot(x, 2 * y ** 2 - 1, color='r')
ax4.set_title("a red line")

plt.show()
```

[image: with titles]]

Comment: that is not what I want. I want a combined Title for the upper two and the lower two plots that appears in the middle.